# Dark theme CSS problem on page load 1 second gap

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have the following code which change theme to dark on page load. The problem is that there is a 1-second gap and every time I swich to other page, screen flashes for 1 second and then it's dark. How I can replace `document.body.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');` to use `dark` theme immediately after page load?

```
if ($is_dark) {

  echo "
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='$zrcdn_url/css/z-b-u/dark-theme.css'/>
  <script>document.body.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');</script>
  ";

}
```

Also, sometimes script loads faster than CSS and I used this code and it makes even 2-3 seconds gap.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  document.body.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why you don't use `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {}` directly in css and not load separate css file after page render?

Comment: Ok solved by using `echo "<body ".(($is_dark) ? "data-theme='dark'" : '').">";

Comment: The CSS file, maybe will help someone https://static.zareklamy.com/css/z-b-u/dark-theme.css

Answer (score -1):

Try to use first of all the CSS file inside the body or head of html.

```
<style>
body {
  background-color: black;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You can put the code inside the tag too. Like this: <body style="background-color:black"> Keep Simple!

Comment: thats not as good a solution as you think. Other developers/designers would need to then be aware that there is a static styling done in the HTML instead of the CSS where it belongs.